# How to workaround ta.highest() or ta.lowest() functions' error?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image: Crossings]

I am investigating those crossings, see red/green dots. The goal is to validate them if a dot is preceded by a big movement but dropping crossing events when its too calm.

Just ***call the distance between the two plots 'X_hist'***. I'd like to ***watch its highest value since the last crossing event***.

```
BarsSinceCrossingUp = ta.barssince(CrossingUp)
CrossingIsValid = ta.highest(math.abs(X_hist), BarsSinceCrossingUp) > math.abs(X_hist[1]) * 5
```

It fails;

```
Error on bar 22: Invalid value of the 'length' argument (NaN) in the "highest" function. It must be > 0.
```

I thought the following Boolean operation will protect the `ta.highest()` function from `0` or `NaN` values:

```
BarsSinceCrossingUp = // wrapped for readability
     ta.barssince(CrossingUp) < 1 or // handling 0
     na(ta.barssince(CrossingUp)) ? 1 : // handling NaN
     ta.barssince(CrossingUp)

CrossingIsValid = ta.highest(math.abs(X_hist), BarsSinceCrossingUp) > math.abs(X_hist[1]) * 5
```

Error message remained which I don't get why though. How could I make this `ta.highest()` function work? Maybe this `ta.barssince(CrossingUp)` function isn't the proper way to retrieve the number of bars since the last CrossingUp event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using those functions, you can just a `var` variable.

```
var float highest_x = na     // Keep of highest X_hist after a cross

if (CrossingUp)              // New cross, reset the variable
    highest_x := X_hist
else
    if (X_hist > highest_x)  // Check if the current X_hist is greater than our variable
        highest_x := X_hist
```